# Patch request to project user update endpoint fails

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

When I make a patch request to `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/hq/v2/accounts/:account_id/projects/:project_id/users/:user_id`
and pass a list of role ids using the `industry_roles` attribute I get the following response:

```
{'code': 1001, 'message': 'users list about to be imported are empty or in wrong format.'}
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

The body i'm passing in the request is:

```
{
    "company_id": <my company id>,
    "industry_roles": [
      <role id>,
      <role id>
    ]
}
```

Comment: Could you provide your request please?

Comment: @VolodymyrDobrzhanskyi OK, i've updated the question

Comment: Have you tried to pass only one role_id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please ensure the data is passed as JSON with `content-type:application/json` header.